# Difference between Router and RouterTestingModule also Http and HttpTestingModule.Can I pass RouterTestingModule where it expects Router

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test on Angular app, I try to create instance of Component
 this is the constructor

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }
```

so In the unit test I am forced to import formbuilder,router etc. shouldn't httpTestingModule and RouterTestingModule compensate for the above modules??

I am new to unit testing, So, the question might be basic.

This is what I tired 
  let fb :FormBuilder;
  let rt:RouterTestingModule;

so here instead for importing router I imported routerTestingModule, this is not working?

```
 let component: EntitlementCreateComponent = new EntitlementCreateComponent(_httpClient, fb, rt,  NgxSpinnerService);

This is testbed
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports:[HttpClientTestingModule,RouterTestingModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [EntitlementCreateComponent,NGXSpinner],

        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
      })

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntitlementCreateComponent);
```

Comment: `{Thing}TestingModule` defines *alternative* providers for the same things that `{Thing}Module` defines. Use the `TestBed` to do the dependency injection, it's more straightforward than `new`ing up `EntitlementCreateComponent ` yourself. Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe  I have updated my question with testbed, Am I creating the component correctly?

Comment: Well, does it work? I'd expect not. Please spend some actual time reading that documentation. You could also use the Angular CLI, which generates test templates for you.